# byte, char, int in Java - bit representation

Tags: java, char, byte

I am confused with byte and char in Java. I have the following program segment :

```
    byte b = 65;
    char c = 65;
    short s = 65;
    System.out.println("b:"+b+" c:"+c+ " s:"+s);  // outputs b:65 c:A s:65
```

The bit representation of b, c and s are same they all are :: 00000000 01000001 . 
My question is if the bits are same then how they act differently - b as byte, c as char and s as short ?
Another question is : `char c = 65;` why this is a correct statement ? it does not give error though I am assigning int value to a char.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

*how they act differently ?*

Refer the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html):

> The integral types are byte, short, int, and long, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers, respectively, and char, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16 code units.
>
> The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges:
>
> 1. For byte, from -128 to 127, inclusive
> 2. For short, from -32768 to 32767, inclusive
> 3. For int, from -2147483648 to 2147483647, inclusive
> 4. For long, from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807, inclusive
> 5. For char, from '\u0000' to '\uffff' inclusive, that is, from 0 to 65535

Another difference will be their Wrapper Classes differ : `byte` to `Byte` , `char` to `Character` and `short` to `Short`.

*`char c = 65;` why this is a correct statement ?*

> **char**, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16 code units (§3.1).

Answer (score 3):

`byte` is boxed to `Byte`

`char` is boxed to `Character`

`short` is boxed to `Short`

Those 3 classes have 3 different `toString()` method. That's why they have different displays.

Then the conversions from `int` to `byte`, `char`,`short` are done automatically for you, then it is boxed to their corresponding boxing class.

Answer (score 2):

1) their bit representation is not the same, it's `01000001` for byte and `0000000001000001` for short and char.

2) the difference is that byte and short are signed integers and char is a 16-bit Unicode character

3) 65 is not int, it's a constant, if you try to assign an int you will get an error

```
   int x = 65;
   char c = x;   <-- error
```

Comment: `char` *is* a number. It is in fact the only integral numeric type in Java. Your final statement errors out only due to the narrowing conversion, which must be made explicit in Java.

Comment: I do not agree. char is a 16-bit Unicode character, not a number

Comment: You also do not agree with the JLS. See The New Idiot's quote of the JLS. Also try to explain the value of `e` in `char c = 1, d = 1, e = c + d;` without referring to the concept of integers.

Comment: If char had been a number Character would have extended Number

Comment: I must commend you on finding an excuse :) But seriously, that's not very convincing. It's a detail of library design against explicit words of the JLS and the fact that `char`s freely participate in all operations defined on integers, and have all widening/narrowing conversions to other numeric types defined.

Answer (score 1):

They do not behave differently as far data reprezentation is considered, the difference is only that they can hold values in different intervals.

As for char every character has it's integers representation that is why it is a valid syntax in java.

Answer (score 1):

All **primitive types** (`boolean, char, short, int, ...`) are actually bit arrays in memory.

The type of the variable only defines in what range this variable can take value:
holds 16 bit unsigned value

- `boolean` 1 bit [range 0-1]
- `char` 16 bits [range 0 to  65,535 or \u0000 to \uFFFF]
- `byte` 8 bits [range -128 to 127]
- `short` 16 bits [-32768 to 32767]
- `int` 32 bits [-2147483648 to 2147483647]
- ...

---

`char` is represented by bits, or complementary a hex, dec, oct number. It does not matter. That's why you can assign a number to it and then when you call `.toString()` on it, this number is matched to *Unicode* representation of that number.

Comment: I don't understand the char range. Shouldn't it be 0 - 65535? ```jshell> (int) ((char) 0xffff)
$26 ==> 65535
```