# Casting int to char in Java

Tags: java, casting, integer, character

I'm looking for a straightforward answer and can't seem to find one.

I'm just trying to see if the following is valid. I want to take the integer 7 and turn it into the character '7'. Is this allowed:

```
int digit = 7;
char code = (char) digit;
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Integer is not the same as int and Character is not the same as char. Also try it and see if it works.

Comment: `(char) ('0' + digit)` will work

Comment: This might be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984975/convert-int-to-char-in-java

Comment: Simply trying this yourself and outputting the result to the console would answer this question.

Answer (score 4):

This conversion is allowed, but the result won't be what you expect, because [char `7` is the bell character whereas `'7'` is `55` (`0x37`)](http://www.asciitable.com/).  Because the numeric characters are in order, starting with `'0'` at `48` (`0x30`), just add `'0'`, then cast the result as a `char`.

```
char code = (char) (digit + '0');
```

You may also take a look at the [Unicode characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters), of which the printable ASCII characters are the same codes.

Comment: Argh, why point to ASCII when there is Unicode and Java does Unicode? :p

Comment: See my answer as to why refering to ascii is imho not a good thing

Answer (score 1):

[`'7'` is Unicode code point `U+0037`.](http://unicode-table.com/en/)

Since it is a code point in the [Basic Multiligual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_multilingual_plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), and since `char` is a [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) code unit and that there is a one-to-one mapping between Unicode code points in this plane and UTF-16 code units, you can rely on this:

```
(char) ('0' + digit)
```

Do NOT think of `'7'` as ASCII 55 because that prevents a good understanding of `char`... For more details, see [here](http://fgaliegue.blogspot.fr/2014/03/strings-characters-bytes-and-character.html).

Answer (score 1):

Nope. The `char` `'7'` can be retrieved from `int` `7` in these ways:

```
 int digit = 7;
 char code = Integer.toString(digit).charAt(0);
 code = Character.forDigit(digit, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

If digit is between 0 and 9:

```
int digit = 7;
char code = (char)(((int)'0')+digit);
```

Comment: No need to explicitly widen `'0'` to `int`.