# .class expected in Java?

Tags: java, char, java.util.scanner, lexical-analysis

I am trying to get the next char for my scanner.

My constructor is :

```
    public S(InputStream inStream)
    {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
        e = false;  // if input stream is done
        getNextChar(); 
    }
```

my method is:.

```
private void getNextChar()
{
       int data = in.read(); 
       char temp = char (data);
       currentChar = temp;
}
```

I am getting a `'.class' expected error in "getNextChar()"`

Any ideas why?

Comment: `char temp = char (data);` What do you think that does? Why?

Comment: I was trying to cast the data variable to a char since read() returns an int

Comment: As @SotiriosDelimanolis implies, you are attempting to perform a cast but are using incorrect syntax. char temp = (char) data. Though the rest of the code is interesting, that should solve that particular conundrum.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984975/convert-int-to-char-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void getNextChar() throws IOException
{
    int data = in.read(); 
    char temp = (char) data;
    currentChar = temp;
}
```

casting should be done like this: **char temp = (char) data;**

Not like this: **char temp = char (data);**

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wonder why you have a `void` get method. Then I see two unnecessary temporaries and a worrisome attempt at casting,

```
private void getNextChar() {
   int data = in.read(); 
   char temp = char (data);
   currentChar = temp;
}
```

Assuming you really want to also set `currentChar` you can do something like

```
private char getNextChar() {
  return currentChar = (char) in.read(); // <-- chaining assignment
}
```

or perhaps (equivalent to the chaining version),

```
private char getNextChar() {
  currentChar = (char) in.read();
  return currentChat;
}
```

or the far more typical case would be to skip `currentChar` altogether,

```
private char getNextChar() {
  return (char) in.read();
}
```