# Getting weird result from an array of ints

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

What I am trying to accomplish is:
User inputs three arrays of strings for example

> 1, 11, 111; 2, 22, 222, 2222; 3, 33, 333, 3333, 33333

I need to get rid of the `,` 's and put numbers into three arrays but it is storing weird results. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class signum {

    static int[] eja = new int[10000];
    static int[] tja = new int[10000];
    static int[] kja = new int[10000];

    private static String ej = null;
    private static String tj = null;
    private static String kj = null;

    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Write a first array of integers");
        ej = sc.nextLine();

        ej = ej.replaceAll( "[^\\d]", " " );


        System.out.println("Write a second array of integers");
        tj = sc.nextLine();

        tj = tj.replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" );



        System.out.println("Write the third array of integers");
        kj = sc.nextLine();

        kj = kj.replaceAll( "[^\\d]", " " );

        for(int i = 0; i < ej.length(); i++) {

            Character c = ej.charAt(i);

            if(c == '0' || c == '1' || c == '2' || c == '3' || c == '4' ||
                c == '5' || c == '6' || c == '7' || c == '8' || c == '9') {
                eja[i] = c;

                System.out.println(eja[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know it still only tries to store the first array but the point is that if I try to store something like `1, 1, 1` it stored `49, 49, 49`.

Also i still have no idea how to make it store numbers that are `> 9`, any ideas? 
Thanks in advance! I am really out of ideas here..

Comment: Why don't you [split your strings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3481842/264775) and then parse the individual elements using [Integer.parseInt](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5585800/264775)?

Comment: you can assign a char to an int in Java, but in a proper way:

 http://stackoverflow.com/a/17984993/1951298

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading in characters, and then (implicitly) converting them to integers when you store them in your `int[]`. But the problem is that a character of `'1'` doesn't end up as `1` when it gets converted to an `int`, it gets converted to its ASCII value, which is `49`.

You want to read in a whole number, then use `Integer.parseInt(String s)` to convert it to an `int`.

Use `String bits[] = ej.split(",");` to get yourself an array of the `String` representations of the integers, and then use `eja[i] = Integer.parseInt(bits[i].trim())` inside a `for` loop to get each `int`.

(You need the `.trim()` part to remove any extraneous spaces. If you're certain of the exact formatting of each line, you might use `ej.split(", ")` to split on a comma followed by a space, but that will mean it falls over if later on one turns up with extra spaces or no space.)

Comment: Now I see whats the deal here. Thanks alot! I have no clue why I didn't think of that!
Thank you, once again!

Comment: It is still throwing exceptions at me when I am trying to store numbers to an array.
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1  1  1" 
I entered "1, 1, 1"

Comment: @Artur Take out your `replaceAll` lines! You don't want them any more. They're getting rid of the commas before you're splitting your `String`.

Comment: Alright I did it and now I am getting ArrayOutOfBoundsException. But it prints out all the ej[i]'s just fine and then throws the exception.

Comment: @Artur Hard to work out what the error is without seeing the new code, but your `for` loop is probably not quite right. You should be using `for (int i=0; i<bits.length; i++) ...` so that you're adding one element for each thing in the `bits[]` array. You certainly don't want to be using `ej.length()`, or else you will get an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score -1):

Your resulting arrays are of type Integer but you are putting Characters in there. This means that you will see the values differently. Redefine them as following and it will work:

```
static char[] eja = new char[10000];
static char[] tja = new char[10000];
static char[] kja = new char[10000];
```