# how to convert a string of numbers to a char

Tags: java, string, char, ascii

Excuse me if this has been answered previously, but I can't seem to find an answer.

How do I convert a string of numbers (e.g "50") into a single char with an ASCII value of the same number, in this case '2'. Is there a way to do this conversion?

Alternatively, could I do the same by converting the string to an int first?

Comment: For which language?

Comment: My bad. Java, thanks

Comment: OK, look at my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert int to char in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984975/convert-int-to-char-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here for some languages:

C/C++

```
int i = 65;
char c = i;
printf("%c", c); // prints A
```

JS

```
var c = String.fromCharCode(66);
console.log(c); // prints B
```

C#/Java

```
char c = (char)67;
// For Java use System.out.println(c)
Console.WriteLine(c) // prints C
```

Python

```
c = chr(68) # for Python 2 use c = str(unichr(68))
print(c) # Prints D
```

Comment: Mark as solved, by clicking on checkmark on left and upvote.

Comment: Even if the OP is happy that is not what he asks. He wanted to convert from a string that represents a number (e.g. "50") to ascii the character. You are converting from a number.

Comment: @miracle173 No problem, just use string to int converter and then what in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "50";
try {
    char c = (char) Integer.valueOf(s);
    ... c
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    ...
}
```

With catching the NumberFormatException and checking the integer range the code might be made rock-solid.