# .NET 9 Loop optimizations, is it more than remove the zero extension?

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop

So, upon reading new updates in .NET 9, I got attracted to this section about Loop optimizations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-9/overview#loop-optimizations

As I understand, here's what they explained, consider this snippet of code

```
static int Sum(int[] arr)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

The variable i is 4 bytes as it is an integer. The act of using it as an accessor for the array like arr[i] would required to extend i to 8 bytes. This process is called "zero-extend".
For those who don't know, [Zero-extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42171285/what-does-zero-extend-mean) means extend the variable i from 4 bytes to 8 bytes by appending zeroes to "extended" bits. And .NET 9 improve the loop by removing the process of zero extension.

As the example quite simple, I'm curious would this improvement can affect in more complex cases? Like if I using for loop to populate and append object into a list, would it be beneficial?

```
List<ClassA> list = new List<ClassA>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ClassA data = db.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == i);
    data.doSomething();
    list.Add(data)
}
```

Comment: No because the expensive part (by several orders of magnitude, 1K-10Kx and more) is the inefficient and synchronous  `db.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == i);` database query, not the loop. You're executing 10 queries instead of a *single* query that returns all 10 objects at once, eg `var list=await context.Customers.Where(x=>ids.Containx(x.Id)).ToListAsync();`

Comment: That optimization is a micro-optimization, possibly saving just a single instruction in a tight loop executed *billions* of times, which is not the case here.