# beginner in java ((char)num) gives zero why

Tags: java, character

Why when I run this it gives zero instead of the character a:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 79;
    char a = 'a';

    System.out.println((char)num);
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you expected as a result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert int to char in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984975/convert-int-to-char-in-java)

Comment: "instead of the character a" - why do you expect an ``a``?

Comment: *I* have ... :D, the output changes ... ;)

Answer (score 8):

It isn't a zero, it's an uppercase `O`, which [79 is the ASCII code for](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/capital-letter-o-uppercase-ascii-code-79.html).

Answer (score -1):

You have an typo:

To get the lowercase letter 'a', use 97 instead of 79.

Comment: Why the downvote? The question is, why the output is zero and not 'a'. This is exaclty the answer (I have tested it).

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if the problem is just a typo you should comment and flag to close it as off topic rather than adding an answer.

Comment: OK, thank you, I will regard next time

Answer (score -1):

When you cast a number to a character it will look the `ASCII`  value of that particular number which in your case is `O` (CAPITAL O).

If you want to print `a` use `97`

See the ASCII chart for further reference: https://ascii.cl/