# My program changes one letter of a 4 letter word and switches it with something else typed in, then updates

Tags: java

I am a beginner programmer and am trying to figure out what is wrong with my code. How can I fix my mistakes? This is the code I could type out so far. This is pretty similar to the game "Word Ladder". I keep getting this error and cannot understand how to fix this:

```
OneLetterGame.java:67: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char:   charArray[0] = index ;
```

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class OneLetterGame {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String startWord = "";
  String currentWord = "";
  String goalWord = "";
  String error = "";
  char newLetter = '\0';
  int index = 0;
  int steps = 0;

     do {
   String[] fileContents = getFileContents("dictionary.txt");

   startWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(error + "Player One, please enter a FOUR letter word: ");

   if (startWord == null) {
    //exits program if user selects "cancel"
    System.exit(0);
   } //if

   currentWord = startWord;

   /* for(int i = 0; i < fileContents.length;i++){
    if(currentWord.equals(fileContents[i]){
        break;
    }else{
        error = "This is not a valid four letter word. Please try again. \n";
        continue;
    }   

}//for */

   System.out.println(startWord);

   goalWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Player Two, please enter a FOUR letter GOAL word: ");

   if (goalWord == null) {
    //exits program if user selects "cancel"
    System.exit(0);
   } //if                                               

   steps++;

   //user enters step has form index space letter
   currentWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the letter you want to change and its location (ex: 1 a) \n The Goal Word is " + goalWord + " :");

   if (currentWord == null) {
    //exits program if user selects "cancel"
    System.exit(0);
   } //if

   //pulls out character at index 0
   index = currentWord.charAt((int) 0 - 48);
   //pulls out character at index 3
   newLetter = currentWord.charAt(3);

   //string to char
   char[] charArray;
   charArray = currentWord.toCharArray();

   charArray[0] = index;
   charArray[3] = newLetter;
   currentWord = String.valueOf(charArray);

   //char to string
   currentWord = new String(charArray);

   System.out.println(currentWord);



   if (currentWord.equals(goalWord)) {
    if (steps % 2 == 0) {
     System.out.println("Congratulations to Player2. You won in " + steps + " step(s)!");
    } else {
     System.out.println("Congratulations to Player1. You won in " + steps + " step(s)!");
    }
    break;
   } else {
    continue;
   }
  } while (true);

 } //main

 public static String[] getFileContents(String fileName) {

  String[] contents = null;
  int length = 0;
  int num = 0;
  try {
   // input
   String folderName = "/subFolder/"; // if the file is contained in the same folder as the .class file, make this equal to the empty string
   String resource = fileName;

   // this is the path within the jar file
   InputStream input = OneLetterGame.class.getResourceAsStream(folderName + resource);
   if (input == null) {
    // this is how we load file within editor (eg eclipse)
    input = OneLetterGame.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resource);
   }
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));



   in .mark(Short.MAX_VALUE); // see api

   // count number of lines in file
   while ( in .readLine() != null) {
    length++;
   }

   in .reset(); // rewind the reader to the start of file
   contents = new String[length]; // give size to contents array

   // read in contents of file and print to screen
   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    contents[i] = in .readLine();
   } in .close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("File Input Error");
  }

  return contents;

 } // getFileContents
}//onelettergame
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984975/convert-int-to-char-in-java/30654145)

You are trying to assign a `char` type to an `int` value. Try casting to type char like this instead:

```
charArray[0] = (char) index;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do casting properly use --> charArray[0] = (char) index;

Although if you are doing this in some IDE then compilation error will shown something like this --> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to char