# How do I convert a random number in to a character

Tags: java, random, ascii

I have tried to convert a random number into a character.
If I type a number into a variable it works, but if I do this `int number = (int)(Math.random()*10);` and then to assign it to a char and convert it `char c = (char)number;` when I print it, it shows nothing without errors like an invisible character.
Could you help me to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert int to char in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984975/convert-int-to-char-in-java)

Comment: I've already tried this but it doesn't work :'(

Comment: you tried exactly what? I would use `Character.forDigit(number, 10)`

Comment: My problem was that the first characters os the ASCII table were like null characters, but if I start at least from 33 it works correctly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because you are getting a number from `0` to `9` which corresponds to a non-printable character. Try the following code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = new Random().nextInt((126 - 33) + 1) + 33;
        char c = (char) number;
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

This will print some character from the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) range of 33 to 126.

Comment: `int number = (int) (Math.random() * 100);` - this does not guarantee a printable character.

Comment: @HarshalParekh - I had given that example to show that there was a greater probability with a bigger number. I've removed that block now.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `'0'` to your `int`.

```
int number = (int)(Math.random()*10);
char c = (char)number + '0';
```

Since `'0'` is ASCII value 48, `'1'` is 49, etc..., any number from 0 to 9 you sum to it will result in a number whose ASCII value is between between `'0'` and `'9'`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a random from 0 to 9. And when trying to convert that to an integer you can have this possible values from the ASCII table

```
Dec  Char                         
---------                         
  0  NUL (null)                   
  1  SOH (start of heading)       
  2  STX (start of text)          
  3  ETX (end of text)            
  4  EOT (end of transmission)    
  5  ENQ (enquiry)                
  6  ACK (acknowledge)            
  7  BEL (bell)                   
  8  BS  (backspace)              
  9  TAB (horizontal tab)         
 10  LF  (NL line feed, new line)
```

So you need to check the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the Char to use

Answer (score 0):

Use an Integer and convert to String.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer number = new Integer(Math.random() * 10);
        String c = number.toString();
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: why create an `Integer`, just use the static method `Integer.toString(int)