# Convert a int digit to a char (example: from 1 to '1')

Tags: visual-c++

I'd like to convert a int digit to a char (no to convert from ascii code). I'd like to convert it from int type to char type. (Example: from 5 to '5') Is it possible?

Comment: Unclear. Are you looking to *print* the digit? `cout`. Are you looking to cast the *type* of the variable? `static_cast<char>`. Something else? Please be a bit more specific.

Comment: I'd like to cast to a char

Comment: Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984975/convert-int-to-char-in-java) with same question on stackoverflow.

Comment: It crashes when it executes that line of code

Comment: Are you looking for `int x = 5; char c = '0' + x;  // c == '5'` ?

Comment: It delivers very intresting values: 5P≈^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use:

```
int x = 5; char c = '0' + x;  // c == '5'
```